# TypeScript compile error TS2322 when assigning a value of a generic type

Tags: generics, typescript

I am trying to create a TypeScript function that has two type parameters, where one type parameter uses the other one:

```
interface Wrapper<T> {
    value: T;
}

function func<T, W extends Wrapper<T>>(val: T, takesWrapper: (w: W) => void) {
    const wrapper: W = { value: val };
    takesWrapper(wrapper);
}

func(32, num => { console.log(Math.abs(num.value) + 10); });
```

The TypeScript compiler yields an error for the line `const wrapper: W = { value: val };`:

```
test.ts(6,11): error TS2322: Type '{ value: T; }' is not assignable to type 'W'.
```

However, as `W` extends `Wrapper<T>`, the assigned value `{ value: val }` where `val` is of type `T` should be valid.

Why does the TypeScript compiler yield a compile error in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating object that might be not assignable to `W`. For example:

```
interface ExtendedWrapper<T> extends Wrapper<T>{
    anotherValue: T;
}
```

`{ value: 1 }` is not assignable to `ExtendedWrapper<number>` (property *anotherValue* is missing).

You can overcome this using type assertion `const wrapper = { value: val } as W;` but keep in mind that `takesWrapper` function expects extended type.