# Typescript generic interface parameter assignment

Tags: typescript, generics

I’m struggling to understand why this example isn’t considered valid by the typescript compiler:

```js
interface IExample<T> {
  param: T
}

function testFunc<U, I extends IExample<U>>(myParam: U): I {
  return { param: myParam };
}
```

The error produced is:

```
Type 'U' is not assignable to type 'I["param"]'.
```

My (assumedly incorrect) reading of this snippet is:

- `IExample<T>` expects `param` to have type `T`.
- `I` is a subtype of `IExample<U>`, meaning `param` has type `U`.
- `myParam` has type `U` from the parameter annotation.
- Therefore `myParam` should be a valid value for `param` of `I`.

Prefixing the return value with `<I>` clears the error, so why does the error appear in the first place?

Comment: I would have expected a different error message: something like `{ param: U }` isn't assignable to generic type `I`: I is an unknown type, which could have many more attributes and methods than just param. So `{ param: myParam }` is almost guaranteed to not be of type I.

Comment: Found a duplicate which I missed before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690797/1813169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `I` might have other required properties in addition to `param`. Typescript will force your generic function implementation to return a valid value for any `I` that satisfies the constraint of extending `IExample<U>`, and it does not.

For example:

```
interface DerivedIExample extends IExample<number> {
  other : string
} 
let o = testFunc<number, DerivedIExample>(0)
o.other // required by the DerivedIExample but not assigned
```

In your simple example, it would be best to do away with `I` completely:

```
function testFunc<U>(myParam: U): IExample<U> {
  return { param: myParam };
}
```

You can force the compiler to accept your code using a type assertion but as outlined above that is not type-safe:

```
function testFunc<U, I extends IExample<U>>(myParam: U): I {
  return { param: myParam } as I; // NOT TYPE SAFE! USE WITH CARE !
}
```

Comment: I don’t know why I didn’t just eliminate `I` in the first place, thanks! Is it worth opening an issue to note the unhelpful(/misleading?) error message?

Comment: It turns out the error has already been fixed in the nightly builds, it’s now: `Type '{ param: U; }' is not assignable to type 'I'.`